# Can not log into org with 'My Domain' due to HSTS

Tags: certificates, mydomain

This Monday I have noticed that I can not login my developer org with [custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_overview.htm).

The problem in brief: certificate for *.salesforce.com does not allow to add exception for subdomains.
So I totally blocked - can not log into my salesforce from FF, Safari, Chrome

Did I miss some notification about certificate updates? How can I restore access to my org when I even can not login?

[image]

Error description in chrome:

```
xxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to xxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be xxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.
```

Domain check in https://www.digicert.com/help/
[image]

Comment: I have occasionally had this happen with test.salesforce.com in Firefox, which should be a safe domain mainly when trying to navigate back out of process builder to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of problem was in splitting NA12.

Answer from support:

> The issue is happened because of Developer Edition orgs that have the
>   Communities feature set up unfortunately didn't have their DNS CNAMEs
>   updated with the NA12 split.

It was fixed on Aug, 23 2016

Answer (score 0):

Did you try login.salesforce.com ?

You can still try to login by using your username and password - by adding `/?login` to your custom domain address, but this is more for domains with SSO setup to bypass it.

I also get "Your connection is not secure" and "Certificate not matching domain name" errors sometimes in Chrome on my work laptop, but I'm suspecting some browser's extensions or my company's web filters to cause it and also never happened to salesforce.com for me.

Comment: 1. Yes. I try login.salesforce.com but it redirects me to my custom domain.
2. It does not allow me to add security exception in browser (as you can do with self-signed certificates)

Comment: Try to [submit a case](https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder) with support

Comment: this is the first thing I did. )